how to prove that $\sin x+\sin \pi x$ do not have maximum and minimum values
That's my line of thinking，I feel like there's still something wrong with it
Given that $f(x) \leqslant 2$, if there exists $x_0$ such that $f\left(x_0\right)=2$, then it must be true that $\sin x_0=1$ and $\sin \left(\pi x_0\right)=1$. That is, there must exist integers $n$ and $m$ such that $x_0=2 n \pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\pi x_0=2 m \pi+\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$ Solving this equation gives $\pi=\frac{2 m+\frac{1}{2}}{2 n+\frac{1}{2}}$, which contradicts the fact that $\pi$ is an irrational number. Therefore, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we must have $f(x)<2$.
Let $a_n=2 n+\frac{1}{2}$, then:
$$
f\left(a_n\right)=\sin \left(2 n+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\sin \left(2 n \pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1+\sin \left(2 n+\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
Since $\sin \left(2 n+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is dense in $[-1,1]$, there exists a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ such that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin \left(2 n_k+\frac{1}{2}\right)=1$. Therefore, $\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} f\left(a_{n_k}\right)=2$. Since $f(x)<2$, it follows that $f(x)$ does not have a maximum value. Similarly, it can be proven that $f(x)$ does not have a minimum value.

Your proof is correct, except that you neglected to prove that $\sin(2n + 1/2)$ is dense in $[-1,1]$.

@RobertIsrael  so how to prove that it is dense in [-1,1]， I'm a little confused about that

Just note the values of $xy-\lfloor xy\rfloor$ for integer $x$ are dense in $[0,1]$ for any irrational $y$.
